# ¿ Como solucionar un condicional que no me esta funcionando al hacer un select?

Tags: php

Tengo una base de datos el cual tiene 2 tablas una de salida de producto y la otra de inventario, en `PHP` tengo el código para insertar las salidas y un select para verificar si hay suficiente stock cuando una cantidad de salida es mayor que el stock, mediante una alerta me ponga en aviso, el detalle que tengo es que cuando sale una cantidad minina o maxima al stock me sigue mandando la primera alerta que no hay suficiencia stock.

**Scritpt de salida de producto**

```
CREATE TABLE t_salida_produc_albergue(
idSPA int auto_increment primary key,
codigo_spa varchar(20) not null,
descripcion_pro varchar(30) not null,
cantidad int,
unidadMedida varchar(10) not null,
fechaSalida date,
idUser int,
FOREIGN KEY (idUser) REFERENCES t_usuario (idUser),
KEY codigo_spa (codigo_spa),
CONSTRAINT codigo_spa FOREIGN KEY (codigo_spa) REFERENCES t_producto (codigo_pro)
);
```

**Script inventario**

```
CREATE TABLE t_inventario_albergue(
codigo_ia varchar(20) primary key,
entradas int,
salidas int,
stock int,
KEY codigo_ia (codigo_ia),
CONSTRAINT codigo_ia FOREIGN KEY (codigo_ia) REFERENCES t_producto (codigo_pro)
);
```

**salidaProducto.php**

```
<?php

 include('conexion.php');

 $codigospa = $_POST["codigo_spa"];
 $descriProdu = $_POST["descripcion_pro"];
 $cantidad = $_POST["cantidad"];
 $unidadMedi = $_POST["unidadMedida"];
 $fechaSalida = $_POST["fechaSalida"];

$query = "INSERT INTO t_salida_produc_albergue(codigo_spa,descripcion_pro,cantidad,
unidadMedida,fechaSalida)
VALUES('$codigospa','$descriProdu','$cantidad','$unidadMedi','$fechaSalida')";

$stock =$mysql->query("SELECT stock FROM t_inventario_albergue WHERE codigo_ia = $codigospa");

$result = $mysql->query($query);

if ($cantidad > $stock) {
   echo "No hay suficiente en stock";  
} else{

if ($result) {
   echo "Salida de producto correctamente";

 } else {
  echo "No se ha registrado ninguna salida";
 }
}
$mysql->close();
?>
```

Comment: puedes validar el contenido de las variables mediante un `var_dump($cantidad,$stock)` y pones en tu post que sale en cada uno de los escenarios???

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent me arroja esto NULL bool(false)

Comment: entonces estas evaluando si null==false; lo cual php evaluara como correcto ... tu codigo esta mal entonces ... no estas trayendo los datos correctamente ... o tu select estan fallando ... prueba que tus select traigan datos ...